# LVM thin pool inactive and failed with: No data available

Tags: debian, lvm, storage, thinpool

I am suffering in a problem due to a system crash, I am using LVM-THIN created in proxmox GUI, all lvs is inactive and the lvm seems broken and I saw it needs to fix manually in system log.

After google it, I've tried to use this command to fix the system.

```
lvconvert --repair data/data
```

my vgs:

```
root@cn-hk1:~# vgs
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
data   3 456   0 wz--n- <8.41t <1.82t
```

I can see some lv is active now:

```
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-12966-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13005-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13011-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13014-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13017-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13038-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13059-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13060-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13071-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13081-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13082-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13088-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/data/vm-13090-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13095-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13109-disk-0' [40.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13134-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13141-disk-0' [30.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13151-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13152-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13178-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13179-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13183-disk-0' [30.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13222-disk-0' [30.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13223-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/vm-13229-disk-0' [20.00 GiB] inherit
```

but beyond that, I got this error :

```
root@cn-hk1:/dev/mapper# lvchange -ay /dev/data/vm-13090-disk-0
device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:4) failed: No data available
```

in dmesg:

```
[   76.381436] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
[   76.398883] device-mapper: table: 253:93: thin: Couldn't open thin internal device
```

And I go back to use thin_check command to check the metadata backup by lvconvert --repair, it shows me that:

```
root@cn-hk1:/dev/mapper# thin_check /dev/mapper/data-data_meta0
examining superblock
TRANSACTION_ID=930
METADATA_FREE_BLOCKS=4145151
examining devices tree
  missing devices: [236, 347]
    bad checksum in btree node (block 398964)
  missing devices: [484, -]
    parent key mismatch: parent was 484, but lowest in node was 1 (block 398963)
examining mapping tree
  missing all mappings for devices: [1, 292]
    bad checksum in btree node (block 27584)
```

Any one can help? I am very appreciate it, thank you.